# mysql update select statement with multiple tables and left outer join

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-columns

I have two tables, hires_owner and projects, where hires_owner is a summary table of data in projects. I'd like to update hires_owner periodically with data from projects. Table structure is as follows:

```
**hires_owner**

id INT(11) AUTO-INCREMENT
owner CHAR(25) UNIQUE
hires_total INT(3)

Sample data:
1, tim, 0
2, jack, 3
3, brian, 1
etc.
```

and

```
**projects**

id INT(11) AUTO-INCREMENT
date DATE() **this is the report date stamp, not date of activity
owner CHAR(25)
accept DATE()

sample data:
1, 2014-02-01, jack, 2014-01-02
2, 2014-02-01, jack, 2014-01-03
3, 2014-02-01, tim, NULL
etc.
```

This query gets me the results that I want to push into the hires_owner table:

```
select owner, count(accept) 
from projects 
where date = (select max(date) from projects) 
group by owner
```

... but I can't seem to get the update query correct. Here's one attempt:

```
update hires_owner h
set hires_total = p.Hires   
(select owner, count(accept) as Hires
from projects 
where date = (select max(date) from projects) 
group by owner) p
where p.owner = h.owner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
update
hires_owner h
inner join
(select owner, count(accept) num_c
from projects 
where date = (select max(date) from projects) 
group by owner) p
on h.owner = p.owner
set h.hires_total = num_c
```

Comment: This worked - thank you for the guidance. Not using 'Inner Join' or placing the set statement at the end were my failures. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not specify which owner to update and it is a little bit twisting logic. 
Updated,Let me know the result.

```
update hires_owner set hires_total = p.m
from (select max(count(accept)) as m, owner as o
                   from projects 
                   where date = (select max(date) from projects)
                   group by owner) as p
where hires_owner = p.o;
```

Comment: Getting the following error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select owner, max(count(accept)) as Hires from projects where date = (select ' at line 3..."

Comment: I am actually working on that. do you mind using two queries to do in stead? @tim_schaaf

Comment: Do you mean two sequential queries? I suppose I could?

Comment: @tim_schaaf glad that you have found the working answer, would you mind try if the update-set-from clause works or not?

Comment: Hi @SCV - I tried it out an ran into a syntax error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select max(count(accept)) as m, owner as o from projec' at line 2)